# How to allow multiple records to use one foreign key value in heidisql

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I am using HeidiSQL to create a database.I've been struggling with inserting data into the columns, as i receive the following error " SQL Error (1062) : Duplicate value on "" and key "".I have two tables.

Employee table  which has the following columns

> name varchar (50);
>
> > empId int not null primary key;
> >
> > > Fk_deparmentId int not null;//this is the foreign key from the department table.

in the Department table which has the following columns

> departmentId int not null primary key;
>
> > dep_name varchar(50);

Now my problem is that when i insert values into the employees table the SQL Error(1062):Duplicate entry  on "the value i inserted" and key" the value that matches" is raised. Please help i have checked the data types and collation they match on both columns. and the DepartmentId is set as a foreign key in the employees table.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us two of your insert statements, it looks like you are insrting the same empid twice.

Comment: INSERT INTO Employees (`empId`, `name`, `departmentId`, `password`, `emailAddress`, `surname`, `DOB`, `userName`) VALUES
 (1, 'Nare', 2, 'password12', 'judith@hotmai.com', 'Boshomane', '1992-12-17', 'judithpass'),
 (2, 'Hazel', 2, 'password12', 'koena@hotmail.com', 'Moloto', '1992-12-13', 'koenapass')                                                                    The above statement says that Nare and Hazel belong to the same Department( that is what it to say.)